# Crear ítems en la Toolbar con efecto Fade en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo una actividad con tres pestañas (`tabs`) en las que cada pestaña se visualiza un fragmento distinto y para movimiento entre los fragmentos utilizo un `ViewPager`. Desde los fragmentos inflo la `Toolbar` con el menú correspondiente a cada fragmento.

El problema viene cuando quiero que los items que componen cada menú, aparezcan (cuando se crea el menú del fragmento, es decir, cuando se visualiza) con un efecto fade y que desaparezca con el mismo (cuando se cambia a otro fragmento y se destruye el fragmento anterior).

Con el efecto de aparecer, no he tenido ningún problema. Lo implemente dentro del método `onCreateOptionsMenu()` del fragmento `FragmentInfoCenter.java` y funcionó correctamente, pero no se como realizar el efecto de desaparecer justo antes de que el menú se destruya.

Lo que he conseguido aparece justo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado introducir este efecto en `onDestroyOptionsMenu()`, pero me salta un error diciéndome que el sistema no puede acceder al ítem del menú porque es nulo (obviamente, ya que es el menú el que se esta destruyendo) y también he probado en implementar el código en el método `onOptionsMenuClosed()`, pero resulta que no llega a entrar nunca, es decir, que el sistema pasa de el.

El código del fragmento `FragmentInfoCenter.java` donde realmente se realiza la acción es el siguiente:

```
public class FragmentInfoCenter extends Fragment {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Menu menuFade;
    private ImageView iv;

    public FragmentInfoCenter() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info_center, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        drawerLayout = ((DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        // Icono del menú que quiero aplicar el efecto fade cuando se crea y 
        // cuando se destruye.
        iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item_change, null);

        return view;
    }

    // Aquí he probado a crear el efecto desvanecer del ítem del menú, pero 
    // me salta una excepción
    // diciendome que el ítem del menú es nulo, porque ya lo esta 
    // destruyendo.
    @Override
    public void onDestroyOptionsMenu() {
        /*Animation fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fade_out);
        iv.startAnimation(fade_out);
        menuFade.findItem(R.id.option_change).setActionView(iv);*/
        super.onDestroyOptionsMenu();
    }


    // También he probado a utilizar este método, pero no se porque no llega  
    // a entrar nunca.
    @Override
    public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
        super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
        Animation fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),  R.anim.fade_out);
        iv.startAnimation(fade_out);
        menu.findItem(R.id.option_change).setActionView(iv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Limpio el menú, para que los distintos menús no se acumulen
        if (menu != null) menu.clear();
        // Inflo el menu con el nuevo
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.frag_menu_center, menu);
        // Añado la animación al icono iv declarado en el método onCreate()
        //menuFade = menu;
        Animation fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),     R.anim.fade_in);
        iv.startAnimation(fade_in);
        menu.findItem(R.id.option_change).setActionView(iv);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

El layout `menu_item_change.xml` lo añado a una ImagenView llamada `iv`, que en el método `onCreateOptionsMenu()` le añadiré la animación `fade_id` y la asociare al `menuItem option_change`.

El layout `menu_item_change.xml` es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/change" />
```

El archivo de animación `fade_in.xml` es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

Junto con el contrario `fade_out.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

Estos dos archivos están dentro de la carpeta `res/anim`.

Por utlimo, el menú que aplico a este fragmento es el siguiente (archivo `frag_menu_center.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/option_change"
        android:icon="@drawable/change"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_change" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/option_edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/edit"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_edit" />

</menu>
```

Por más que busco por internet, no encuentro ningún método que se pueda ejecutar justo antes de la destrucción del menú o hay poquísima información sobre ello.

**Solo quiero que cuando el fragmento `Tab 2` cambie cualquier otro fragmento, el icono de las flechas, se desvanezca con efecto fade** y me es increíble creer que no se pueda hacer. También lo pregunto porque ya no se que probar y posiblemente mis conocimiento en Android no alcancen dicho nivel.

**NOTA:** El ejemplo que he puesto (las tres pestañas) puede que sea excesivamente largo como para poner todo el código del proyecto, así que para dejarlo más claro, os dejo este [link](https://mega.nz/#!MIM1wIYJ!0nmCVjBPgYJ7VN1NU2icQe3HJRp633KXUZ927QJ7P5A) donde podéis descargaros el proyecto de ejemplo, listo para exportar a Android Stuido y así, ver más claro lo que quiero conseguir.

Espero que alguien pueda encontrar una solución y disculpad por lo poco explicado que estaba en un primer momento.

Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Hola Vicky, revisa la [guía para hacer una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo hacer un ejemplo mínimo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que edites tu pregunta y se ajuste al estándar de calidad de la comunidad. Te recomiendo encarecidamente que dividas tu pregunta y problemas más pequeños y que no pidas opiniones ni ideas, sino soluciones a problemas concretos. Por último, te recuerdo que Stackoverflow en español no es un sustituto de Google, por lo que la investigación va por tu cuenta.

Comment: Mira con eso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434704/add-actionbar-items-with-a-fade-animation, no dejas muy claro lo que quieres realmente, si puedes aportar algo más gráfico.

Comment: Perdona por lo mal explicado que estaba. Acabo de editarlo intentando dejarlo más claro.

Comment: Voto por abrir esta pregunta ya que contiene datos necesarios para plantear la pregunta.

Comment: Mirando como cambiar el color de los items en la toolbar, tal vez una alternativa al fadeout seria, runnable que cambie el color hacia transparente y cuando llegue, quitarlo https://gist.github.com/jaredrummler/ec7dfb73f3235ad8e951

Comment: Lo has podido ya solventar? dejo otra cosa a ver si funciona http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638577/how-to-animate-toolbar-overflow-menu-icon

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, yo lo haría desde la actividad, usando OnPageChangeListener:

```
int tab2 = 1;
public ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pagerChangeListener() {
    return new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            iv.startAnimation(position != tab2 ? fade_out : fade_in);
            iv.setVisibility(position != tab2 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE)
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    };
}
 yourViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pagerChangeListener());
```

Entonces lo que va a ocurrir es que al cambiar de tab el `onPageSelected` mira en que posición estás y si no te encuentras dentro de la tab2 hace un fadeOut y si te encuentras en la misma hace un fadeIn.

Espero que te ayude, un saludo.

Comment: Funciona de cierta forma, porque cuando yo estoy en la `Tab 2` y paso a la `Tab 1` el icono de las flechas (el que quiero que tenga el efecto) se solapa encima del icono del lápiz. Supuse que era por que utilizaba varios menús y utilice el mismo menú para  `Tab 1` y `Tab 2` y es cuando los errores empezaron a salir. Ojala hubiese funcionado, porque desde la `Tab 2` (con menú) a la `Tab 3` (sin menú) funciona perfectamente, pero cuando el paso es entre menús o el mismo, da error. Gracias igualmente.

Comment: ¿Estás volviendo a crear el menú al entrar en el tab 1 y 2?

Comment: En tu fragments onCreateOptionsMenu pon super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater); y prueba de nuevo con esa respuesta

Comment: @Webserveis incluyendo eso, pasa absolutamente lo mismo, se solapa el icono de las flechas junto con el del lápiz, tanto en en cambio de la `Tab 2` a la `Tab 1` como de la `Tab 2` a la `Tab 1`.

Comment: @VickyVicent y si haces fadein fadeout en la toolbar no solo e un botón, en toda su totalidad, asi más de un boton si ha cambiado se vera afectado con el efecto

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor Cada fragmento administra su propio menú, por lo que cuando cambio de la Tab 2 a la Tab 1 se crea un nuevo menú sin el icono de las flechas. En mi pregunta, en el código de FragmentInfoCenter.java puedes ver que existe un método onCreateOptionsMenu(), pues en los otros fragmentes se crea igual. ¿Puede que el error este en crear distintos menús para cada fragmento o en que cada fragmento administre su menú?

Comment: @Webserveis no quiero que afecte a toda la toolbar, solo que afecte a los iconos de la derecha de esta. Incluso si lo hiciera para toda la toolbar, el titulo y todos los iconos se verían afectados, por lo haría el efecto fade_in y fade_out, aunque los iconos no cambien. Corrígeme si me equivoco, pero aun así gracias.

Comment: Okey, explicame que ocurre cuando le das al lápiz pls

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor El lápiz hará que se abra una nueva ventana, pero eso no lo he puesto porque la acción de los botones se implementa en el método `onOptionsItemSelected()`. No quiero que haga el efecto cuando pulses el botón si no cuando el menú cambia. Si no entendéis cualquier cosa, avisadme y rectificare. Gracias.

Comment: Okey pues entonces no destruyas y vuelvas a crear el optionsMenu simplemente que cada fragment tenga su propio onOptionsItemSelected() y el  setHasOptionsMenu(true); y me cuentas

Comment: Con  método onPrepareOptionsMenu prueba algo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704700/different-menu-for-different-fragments

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con la librería [AnimatedToolbar](https://github.com/S64/android-animated-toolbar)

En la imágen se puede apreciar que los items tienen efecto `fadeIn` y `FadeOut`

[image: Image of animated toolbar]